# How to append value to p tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a p tag in such way like below,

```
<p id="ES_name">(TEST)</p>
```

But here I want to append this test value from jQuery.
I tried the following but not working,

```
('#ES_name').append('(TEST)');
```

Can any one please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you are missing the [`$` of jQuery](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0-7Xx0oHXAhVKvY8KHXANAa4QFgg7MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8667736%2Fwhat-does-the-sign-mean-in-jquery-or-javascript&usg=AOvVaw1hY9rShgITANo1rNj1fnxN) object

```
$('#ES_name').append('(TEST)');
```

Comment: Is this how you got to 12.2k...?

Comment: @ChrisG what is that derogatory comment supposed to mean? [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: The question shows ZERO research effort. ZERO. Are we supposed to reward those with answers, while also being rewarded with points ourselves? If so, ok then, and sorry. But I thought SO is the one site that doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ohhh... @ChrisG. its just a very basic syntax of the jquery And also  I have added the use of `$` from some other question link.But you are mention answer was not useful it's not fare.And also your first comment is not the right way to ask like this.if you are doubt with me.go and see my profile.

Comment: @ChrisG that is a reasonable comment. The first one is not

Comment: @prasanth Did you misunderstand? I said, the *question* shows zero research effort. Your answer is fine in theory, apart from the fact that you're enabling vampires.

Comment: ya... but your first comment target with my reputation not a question @ChrisG

Comment: @prasanth I'm talking about **TRAVELLER'S jQUERY** question, the one you answered. My first comment was rude, but I was simply frustrated by your enabling vampires. Don't do that. Flag and move on. I thought a 12.2k user would know better.

Comment: @ChrisG .. hahaha :-)...This is not a that much of complicated question.It's just a very basic syntax problem. it's more enough to understand the purpose `$`.Reputation not given depend on the number of words in answer.it depends on the usage of the answer

Comment: @ChrisG if you say  `Flag and move on` .You also downvote and move on. Then why you are asking with my reputation in the first comment.

Comment: @prasanth Like I said. You are feeding vampires. But you should know better. I don't know how to make you understand my point. Here's a good answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87609

Comment: @ChrisG ya... your comment is good. I was understood.but you are mention with my first comment is not related to the last comment .your are just change the topic. if you say the vampire problems directly post with the first comment.Then why you ask like that

Comment: @prasanth Yes. I simply assumed that a 12.2k user would know about vampires. And know not to feed them. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#ES_name').append('(TEST)');
```

you need to write the dollar symbol in order to user jQuery